# About PDE of the form $u_{tt} - u_{xx} -u=0$

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, power-series

I am trying to answer the following question:

> Given the equation:
>   $$
> \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
> u_{tt} - u_{xx} -u=0 , \mathbb{R}\times (0,\infty) \\
> u(x,0)=x , u_t(x, 0)=-x
> \end{array} \right.
> $$
>   Find a solution as a power series expansion about the origin and identify this solution.

I'm kind confused with the written of the problem itself. Am I supposed to assume that there is a solution as a power series and find its form? I tried this way, but couldn't get any reasonable expression for it. Or how should I solve this kind of problem?

Thanks in advance, for any help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are said to solve the problem using a series expansion, you should suppose that such a power series exists. After finding the closed form, you can find the disk of convergence over which the power series is convergent and valid.

Actually, this PDE is classified as linear. A general method for such equations can be substituting the variables or using the separation of variables as $$u(x,t)=f(x)g(t)$$and applying the initial condition.

**Remark**

A power series for a bivariate $u(x,t)$ can be written as $$u(x,t)=\sum_m\sum_n a_{mn}x^mt^n$$

Comment: I add some of my calculation so far.

Comment: By power series, I think they mean $$u(x,t)=\sum_m\sum_n a_{mn}x^mt^n$$

Comment: with $a_{m, n}$ functions of $x, t$ or constants?

Comment: If $t$ appears in the series, it doesnt satisfy the initial condition, right? Cuz we will have $u(x, 0)=0$, not equal $x$

Comment: This means $a_{mn}=0$ for $n< 0$ and $a_{10}=1$. Also $\{a_{mn}\}$ are indexed constants

Comment: @MostafaAyaz I don't think we can solve this problem by method of separation of variables.

Comment: Yes we can. After simplifications we are left with $${g''(t)\over g(t)}-{f''(x)\over f(x)}-1=0$$

Comment: @MostafaAyaz No, it is not possible, because to solve two ordinary differential equations of second order you also need boundary conditions to remove four constants, but here spatial domain is unbounded.

Comment: @MostafaAyaz If it is true, then we could also have solved infinite string problem (1-D wave equation) by method of separation of variables, but we apply other methods like canonical forms or plane wave solutions

Answer (score 0):

Consider the Cauchy problem for second order PDE:
$$ u_{tt}=F(t,x,u,u_{t},u_{tx},u_{xx}),~ u(0,x)=f(x),~u_{t}(0,x)=g(x). $$
Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are analytic in a neighborhood of origin of $\mathbb{R}$ and suppose that $F$ is analytic in a neighborhood of point $(0,0,f(0),g(0),f^{(1)}(0),g^{(1)}(0),f^{(2)}(0))$ of $\mathbb{R}^{7}$. Then Cauchy-Kovalevsky theorem assert that the given Cauchy problem has solution $u(t,x)$ which is analytic in neighborhood of origin of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and the solution is unique in class of analytic functions.

$\textbf{Edit:} ~$Under these assumptions, you can find Taylor series for $u(t,x)$ around origin. 
If you expand $u(t,x)$ around $(0,0)$, then $$ u(t,x)=x-tx+\frac{xt^{2}}{2!}
-\frac{xt^{3}}{3!}+...  $$ So, solution in closed form is $u(t,x)=x \text{e}^{-t}$

Comment: Thanks. But I wanst been able to do so. I took the derivative over the series, but I couldnt find any closed form to it.

Comment: @ArkPDEnational  Edited my answer, I hope it is clear now. When you will find partial derivatives of u, most of them at $(0,0)$ will be zero.